# Get length of a string with data-link

Tags: jsviews

I would like to display the length of the text in my textarea. But since I don't want to build an event handler for it, I would like to try to solve this with the data-link. Unfortunately I don't find a way to do this.

```
<textarea id="commentText" data-link="commentText()"></textarea>
<span><span id="commentTextLength">{^{>commentText().length}}</span>/300</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the expression from `commentText().length` to `commentText()^length`.

See  ["deep linking"](https://www.jsviews.com/#linked-paths@deep).

In that way you make the expression update whenever there is an observable change in `commentText()` itself.

So you can write:

```html
{^{>commentText()^length}}
```

or

```html
<span data-link="commentText()^length"></span>
```

This works equally whether you are using a plain string value `commentText^length` or a computed observable `commentText()^length` as in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried it, but it doesn't work. I get an error in the console when I try the '`{^{>commentText()^length}}` way'.

"jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

When i use the `commentText^length` it shows always '1'. I think it means that he counts the 1 textarea and not its content.
I am still very new at this subject. I will definitely take a look at the "DeepLink".

Comment: Maybe you are making some other error. Can you create a jsfiddle sample showing what you are doing, with the jQuery.Deferred exception?

Comment: Here is a working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/n3wt69cz/